Bitcoin Core and two computers in local+Internet network
I have two computers and both have whole blockchain. However I run one computer first, than second, and Bitcoin Core on both. Both are syncing but from Internet.
What configuration options should I use to make one computer stay connected to second Bitcoin Core, that one would sync blockchain from the other through local network?

If you want one of your two nodes to only connect to the other one in the local network, use the connect command. If you want to be connected to the global network and the local node use the addnode command.
During the synchronization you may want to use connect to ensure that it only requests the blockchain from the other local node to save bandwidth.
